# How to debug an OutOfMemoryException in a webapp

Tags: java, performance, spring, jakarta-ee, out-of-memory

I am trying to debug an out of memory error. When I do a heap dump with Jmap and analyze the results with eclipse Mat - I see the following.

```
7,677 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by 
"<system class loader>" occupy 48,094,720 (23.99%) bytes.
```

Biggest instances:

```
class blah.BlahService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4a0a7d43 @ 0x2aaab06d9668 
- 2,067,096 (1.03%) bytes.
```

BlahService is a spring service with @Service annotation. All service classes are Singleton in spring - one per IOC per bean - So why would this class be a top suspect.

I also see

```
One instance of "org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet" loaded by 
"org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader @ 0x2aaac17bc260" occupies 42,724,168 
(21.31%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of 
"java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

what does this mean?

Comment: You are only showing objects that occupy less than 100 MiB of memory. This is not much for Tomcat application. Can't you see any other memory-hungry objects? Maybe you should just increase your heap size (`-mx`), defaults are way too low for Tomcat/Spring.

Comment: Do you mean **OutOfMemoryError** ?

OutOfMemoryException doesn't exist in the Java API.

That's not an exception but an error, and I think you cannot recover from it.

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryError usually signifies one of the two problems:
1. Either you have too little memory for your application needs. Then you need increase the heap size for your server using Xmx startup parameter
2. Or you have a memory leak in your application or in one of the 3rd party libraries it uses. To track memory leak is not an easy task without prior experience. I can recommend [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu). It is quite easy to use and precise tool for monitoring memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that error sows up when it's too late to do something to fixed it, that because once the heap gets filled the JVM simply can't do anything since it can't create objects to do something, in other hand, since you're using Spring i guess you're doing a Web System, in that case all you have to do is give more heap space at the beginning in the deploy command (it's something like '-Xms:256') and have planned how many resources your app will be need, because it's a fact, if the memory gets filled the system is going to break down

Answer (score 0):

i have used java profilers but i am not satisfied with output for actual performance tuning and memory usage currently we have been switched to [java melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). This not only help performance optimization in dev but also in production system. Java melody is very easy to integrate and configure and in production you can enable or disable by just updating web.xml